# KableExtra + R tune caption (Font, size, color, etc...)

Tags: r, kableextra

I cannot find the option to tune the font size and other caption parameters in kableExtra.

Have a look at the following

```
kable(dt, "latex", caption = "Demo table", booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want this for all captions? Then, the following should do the trick.

````
---
title: "Demo"
author: "H"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
    - \captionsetup{font=Huge}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library("kableExtra")

kable(head(mtcars), "latex", caption = "Demo table", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```
````